# Can’t get freestyle to render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, freestyle, wireframe

I am trying to render the wire frame of (any) model using freestyle. I have followed every tutorial I could find, and no matter what settings I check or uncheck, the outline never renders.

I have tried Eevee and cycles and nothing happens. I have tried messing around with the node editor and if I render freestyle as it’s own pass, it’s just an empty layer no matter what I do.

This is my first time using blender (2.92) so it’s very possible I could be missing something, but I feel like all my settings match all the tutorials I’ve seen. I’ve only been trying to render on the default cube. What could I be missing?

Comment: Just one thing to eliminate first.. currently, Freestyle is not previewed. It appears only in renders through a camera... and it must be switched on in the Render settings.

Comment: Yes! After messing around with it, I noticed you could not view freestyle in the viewport. But even by just enabling it and then trying to render the model (basic cube), no outlines appear. I have tried waiting to see if it shows up, but only the model renders. I’m stumped!

Comment: OK, next, set the lines crazy thick, and a crazy color. Set the Line Set to pick up 'Edge Marks', and mark all edges as Freestyle. Just to get rid of the easy things first.

Comment: No luck there unfortunately. Set the thickness to 30 and color to a bright pink and no outlines rendered.

Comment: Hmm maybe share your file on https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you for your patience! https://pasteall.org/blend/820b99353564415cb7da686d24a8eb89

Comment: That file works fine on my machine, big pink outlines on render. Weird, maybe try re-installing Blender?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I figured it out! For some reason you cannot have "Freestyle SVG Exporter" and "Freestyle" both enabled in the render properties. By unchecking "freestyle SVG exporter", I finally could see an outline!

Comment: That's a weird one. Well done. Good to know.